# then $f$ is an open map, true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $$f(z)=x+y$$ then $f$ is an open map, true?

Comment: By $x$ you mean $\textrm{Re}(z)$ and $y=\textrm{Im}(z)$? In that case yes, as then it's a sum of two open projections, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is open, let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $U$ an open subset containing $z$, there exists an open ball $B(z,r)\subset U$, Write $z=x+iy$, you have $x+t+iy\in B(z,r)$ for $|t|<r$, $f(x+t+iy, |t|<r)$ is $(x+y+t, |t|<r)$ which is an open interval containing $f(z)$.